# Akka Websocket complete, but client still connected

Tags: websocket, akka, akka-stream

(Akka 2.6.5, akka-http 10.1.12)

I have a server/client websocket setup using `Source.queue` and `Sink.actorRef` on each side of the connection.

It turns out my system has a rather critical and unexpected flaw (found in production no less):

1. Sink actor fails and terminates (Dead letters are logged)
2. Sink actor is sent Stream Failure message (configured in `Sink.actorRef` construction) - this also is logged at dead letters, since the actor is indeed dead.

So we have a finished web socket stream right? That's what [Half-closed websockets](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html#half-closed-client-websockets) would say (although, just noticing the heading id is "half-closed-*client*-websockets...)

What happens instead is... nothing. The connected client stays connected - there's no complete message or failure.

Is there something configuration I need to actively tell akka to fully close Http on failures like this?

## Testing

I reproduced the issue in integrated testing:

1. Establish connection
2. Sleep for 70 seconds (just to ensure keep-alives are configured/working properly)
3. Send a message from server
4. Ensure receipt on client
5. Kill server actor sink (and see same Stream Failure -> dead letters as above)
6. Wait for client to acknowledge completion (100 seconds) - either:

   - If I did nothing -> Timeout
   - If I sent message from client to server before waiting for completion:

     1. After 60s: `Aborting tcp connection ... because of upstream failure: TcpIdleTimeoutException`
     2. Stream failed sent to client sink.

## Notes

I've **deliberately not included code** at this stage because I'm trying to understand the technology properly - either I've found a bug, or a fundamental misunderstanding of how the web sockets are meant to work (and fail). **If you think I should include code, you'll need to convince me on  how it might help create an answer**

In production, this failure to close meant that the websocket client was waiting for data for 12 hours (it wasn't attempting to send messages at the time)

Comment: Is there any logging indicating the cause of the error for your Sink.actorRef failing?  You could try enable logging, and configure `akka.actor.debug.lifecycle = on` (warning, will produce a lot of log output) to see if any more details are included in the log for the failure of the actor.

Comment: @SeanGlover It was a Null Pointer. The actor sink definitely should have blown up (good), and the Dead Letters also registered the stream failure message (also good).  But why-oh-why didn't the socket get closed? It should right? My expectation is that it's a bug, but perhaps my expectations are off.